# Need a loop counter

Tags: c#, loops

i need to add a counter to my loop that does a specific task at loop 5 that stops the original loop in c# any ideas how i can do this?

```
IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject hazard = hazards[Random.Range(0, hazards.Length)];
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), spawnValues.y, spawnValues.z);
            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            Instantiate(hazard, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);

        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);

        if (gameOver)
        {
            restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
            restart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (i ==5) { do something; break; }

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to stop your main loop that is using a "true" condition. If that's the case, you can just use a new variable "counter = 0", and when counter reaches counter = 5, then change the condition to false.

If that is not the loop you are talking about, just as someone said, you can use "i" as a reference or if you like to work with many variables add the new variable and add an "if" that does the action when it reaches 5, if you also want to stop the main loop just change the condition to false.

I hope this can help you, good luck.

Answer2:

I'm supposing you're doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
        {

             if(i==5)
                 {
                       %This is your acction
                 }


            GameObject hazard = hazards[Random.Range(0, hazards.Length)];
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), spawnValues.y, spawnValues.z);
            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            Instantiate(hazard, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);

       }
```

But if you don't want to the rest be done, then just make it part of the if in the else part, that way only the 5th time will be done the action but no the spawn thing. If the error keeps going I really don't know how to help.

Comment: ive made a "i==5" statement and told it to do a task but im getting an "unreachable code detected" from it

Comment: With another variable happens the same?, it shouldn't because you are using a local variable.

Comment: Check the edit I've made, but if you want to stop the loop you can just make i=hazardCount and that will take you out of the loop.